# Passing one function output to other function in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have to create a variable named $Project only once. Multiple ports of an instrument needs to be created under this project. Without any function call the code looks like this:

```
 set Project(1) [stc::create "Project" \
    -SelectedTechnologyProfiles {eoam ospfv2 isis dhcp} \
    -ConfigurationFileName {new.tcl} \
    -Active "TRUE" \
    -LocalActive "TRUE" \
    -Name {Project 1} ]

    # create ports
    set Port(1) [stc::create port -under $Project(1) -location //$ipaddress/1/1 ]

    set Port(2) [stc::create port -under $Project(1) -location //$ipaddress/1/2 ]
```

Now, if I create one procedure named "create_project" and another procedure named "create_ports" (which might be called multiple times depending on the number of ports), then my question is how can I pass $Project to create_ports? Should create_project return $Project and I have to pass again $Project to create_ports? Or, there is some easier way to achieve this?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain command calls easily enough; the `[`…`]` syntax is entirely general.

```
set port [stc::create port -under [stc::create Project ...] ...]
```

Whether it is a good idea to do this depends entirely on what your program is doing. (The rules apply to procedures the same as any other commands; procedures are just commands that happen to be implemented using scripts that run with a local stack frame.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to something like:

```
proc create_project {name number} {
    return [stc::create "Project" \
        -SelectedTechnologyProfiles {eoam ospfv2 isis dhcp} \
        -ConfigurationFileName new.tcl \
        -Active TRUE \
        -LocalActive TRUE \
        -Name "$name $number" \
    ]
}

proc create_port {project number} {
    global ipaddress
    return [stc::create port -under $project -location //$ipaddress/1/$number ]
}

set pname "Project"
set pnum 1
set proj($pname,$pnum) [create_project $pname $pnum]
# create ports
for {set i 1} {$i <= 5} {incr i} {
    set port($i) [create_port $proj($pname,$pnum) $i]
}
```